# HAPROXY Hiding Multiple URL behind one common subdomain

Tags: load-balancing, haproxy

We have multiple URL which needs to be masked or redirected to the common URL like below.

```
test.example.com/app > applicaiton.abc-test.example.com/app
test.example.com/web > webapp.abc-test.example.com/web
test.example.com/java > javaapp.abc-test.example.com/java
```

On the right-hand side, the actual running URL is mentioned.
On the left side, the URL used is actually not running anything.

We need a solution which can achieve our requirements. which can allow adding SSL certificate.

```
frontend oc_http_frontend
    bind :80
    default_backend oc_http_backend
    mode http
    acl is_domain_nc hdr(host) -i test.example.com
    use_backend HTTP_MasDB_001 if is_domain_nc

backend HTTP_MasDB_001
    mode tcp
    reqrep ^([^\ ]*)\ (.*) \1\ /path/\2
    balance source
    server cp1 192.168.1.2:443 check
    server cp2 192.168.1.3:443 check
    server cp3 192.168.1.4:443 check
    server w1 192.168.1.5:443 check
    server w2 192.168.1.6:443 check
    server w3 192.168.1.7:443 check
```

We tried implementing the above & accessing test.example.com it showed "Error 502", Seems we are doing something wrong and need expert advice.